# Using NHibernate's ISession.Get<>() w/ a composite key

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, composite-key

I have a composite key in a database table / NHibernate entity. Can I somehow use the `.Get` method to grab a specific entity or do I have to use HQL / Criteria due to the composite key?

Answer (score 26):

With this composite key mapping:

```
<class name="MyClass">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="Key1" />
        <key-property name="Key2" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="..." />
</class>
```

...you can use .Get like this:

```
var x = Session.Get<MyClass>(new MyClass() { Key1 = 'Foo', Key2 = 'Bar'});
```

Comment: This even works with composite IDs that include referenced classes. Just construct the object graph containing the IDs requested.

Comment: Just want to mention that this will not work with an anonymous class.