# NHibernate Select data from table based on non-primary key column

Tags: c#, select, nhibernate, primary-key

I'm brand new to NHibernate and have been fiddling with selecting from a single table based on a criteria. I read that using IQuery is unnecessary if I only want to select data based on an ID, and that I should use session.Get(id).

This works perfectly for selecting based on the primary key value of the table, but I couldn't figure out how to select data based on another unique column that isn't the primary key. Is there a way to use session.Get to do this, or am I heading in the wrong direction?

In short:

1. `session.Get<T>(primary key value)` will return data
2. `session.Get<T>(not primary key value)` will return null

Is there a way to do 2?

Comment: This may work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274969/using-nhibernates-isession-get-w-a-composite-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use Get or Load without an ID, as by nature, they are pulling a single record via it's unique identity.

If you want to pull records out of the table, then you need to issue a query with the criteria you are looking for.

Example :

```
var whateverRecord = session.Query<WhateverType>().Where(x=>x.WhateverColumn == WhateverValue).FirstOrDefault();
```