# NHibernate ISession.Get() on entity with composite key throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, vb.net, nhibernate

The Get() method of NHibernate's ISession throws an InvalidCastException when called on an entity with composite key.

```
System.InvalidCastException : <>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int16, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

I can't see no hint in [NHibernate Documenatation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata-loading) on ISession.Get() and composite keys. Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274969/using-nhibernates-isession-get-w-a-composite-key/4829372#4829372) and [blog posts](http://manishdalal.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/nhibernate-get-on-composite-key/) however suggest that we can call ISession.Get() with an anonymous type as id.

At first I thought this problem would only apply to VB.Net as it uses slightly different implementation of anonymous types. Therefore I rewrote the test case in C# with no more success. Is there something wrong with my code?

My testing code:

Entity:

```
public class Composite1
{

    // Test with composite key

    public virtual short Key1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Key2 { get; set; }

    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Composite1 o = obj as Composite1;
        if (o==null) return false;
        return o.Key1.Equals(this.Key1) && o.Key2.Equals(this.Key2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key1.GetHashCode() ^ Key2.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Mapping:

```
class Composite1Map : ClassMap<Composite1>
{

    public Composite1Map()
    {
        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Key1, "Key1")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.Key2, "Key2");
        Map(x => x.Text);
    }

}
```

GetByID in repository:

```
public Composite1 GetByID(short Key1, string Key2)
{
    return Session.Get<Composite1>(new {Key1 = Key1, Key2 = Key2});
}
```

And the failing test:

```
Composite1 composite1 = composite1Repository.GetByID(1, "Test");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no anonymous class used in either the other answer or the blog post that you link to. What they do is that they use object initializer syntax to initialize an object of the entity class itself.

Comment: Ran into the same issue and could have sworn I seen someone use the `Get` with an anonymous class but apparently that does not work. Works great by using object initializer syntax with the entity itself.